# Testlink 1.9.9(Lone Ranger): Deleting Test Cases is Proving Challenging

Tags: admin, testlink

As an admin user, I find myself unable to delete any test cases currently located under the test specifications. Every attempt to delete a test case results in the following message:

Your role has no right to delete executed test cases or test case versions

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can create a new role from the "user/roles tab" with rights to do this, however the settings do not persist on my installation. Not sure if this is just my installation or a generic issue. I intend to investigate this week and will update.

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to look into this?